Is a molecular Hamiltonian defined uniquely? or Where do differences in pennylane Hamiltonians come from?
For a fixed fermion-qubit mapping, basis, active space, and geometry, is the electronic structure Hamiltonian uniquely defined?
I would think so, since

for a given basis the one- and two-body integrals in the second quantized representation of the Hamiltonian should be unambiguously defined
for a given mapping the translation to Pauli strings should be unambiguously defined.
This assumes that there is a consistent naming in the community and we all understand the exact same transformation by the name 'Jordan-Wigner' for example.

However, this assumption is not consistent with two points:

Constructing a molecular Hamiltonian using pennylane qchem.molecular_hamiltonian with different methods, eg. 'pyscf' and 'dhf' does not give the same Hamiltonian (ignoring some differences in the last digits). The Pauli strings are the same and the absolut values of coefficients are the same, but some terms differ in the sign. So, the one- and two-body terms are not clearly defined by the basis and geometry? Why?
There are pennylane datasets for molecular Hamiltonians calculated with the Jordan-Wigner mapping (eg). This Hamiltonian has the same number of terms and acts on the same number of qubits as the one constructed using qchem.molecular_hamiltonian but otherwise is different.

Where do these differences come from? How are the datasets constructed?
Edit: On the second problem
The two Hamiltonians are equivalent when rounding the coefficients and the eigenspectrum to the 4th decimal. My mistake was forgetting to add the conversion factor between Angstrom (datasets) and Atomic Units (pennylane).

Regarding the first question,

Constructing a molecular Hamiltonian using pennylane
qchem.molecular_hamiltonian with different methods, eg. 'pyscf' and
'dhf' does not give the same Hamiltonian (ignoring some differences
in the last digits). The Pauli strings are the same and the absolut
values of coefficients are the same, but some terms differ in the
sign. So, the one- and two-body terms are not clearly defined by the
basis and geometry? Why?

The flipped signs of molecular integrals are discussed in this PySCF github issue. One way to fix them, is to explicitly define the point group symmetry of your molecule. Please see the following code as an example:
    mol = gto.Mole()
    mol.build(atom = f'''H 0 0 0; H  0 0 1.5; H 0 0 3; H 0 0 4.5''', symmetry='d2h')

You can then manually compute your PySCF integrals and use them to build your Hamiltonian in PennyLane. This PennyLane demo shows you how to do that. Hopefully this resolves the issue of sign change.
Regarding the second point,

There are pennylane datasets for molecular Hamiltonians calculated
with the Jordan-Wigner mapping (eg). This Hamiltonian has the same
number of terms and acts on the same number of qubits as the one
constructed using qchem.molecular_hamiltonian but otherwise is
different.

With the same specifications, e.g., atomic coordinates, basis set and mapping, the two Hamiltonians should be the same. However, the order by which the Hamiltonian terms are stored or printed might be different depending on the method of construction. There might also be some numerical differences in the value of very small coefficients, e.g., 1.3e-5 vs 1.4e-5, because of using different code versions or truncation of terms that have coefficients smaller than a threshold, etc. You might also check the wire orders in the Hamiltonians or construct the Hamiltonian matrices and diagonalize them to compare the actual energies. If you please provide more information about the differences you observed, I will address them with more details. Please also feel free to look at the PennyLane discussion forum in case there are similar discussions.

Welcome to QSE! Nice find on the PySCF issue.

Thank you for the answer on the first point of the flipped signs. This explains it.
